# how to setup webhook on pythonanywhere using "python telegram bot" library

Tags: python, django, bots, telegram, pythonanywhere

can anyone help me? I am deploying my ready bot to pythonanywhere, locally my webhook was working but on pyanywhere I am getting 404 error on getWebhookInfo.
I posted my codes and screenshots Here:
https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/discussions/2952

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Questions here need to be self-contained. Please [edit] a [mre] directly into your question.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run a server on the IP address 127.0.0.1, which is not accessible from outside PythonAnywhere.  You'll need to talk to the team that write the bot about how to set that up so that the endpoints it exposes are visible from a hosted website.

Comment: yeah, but they not responding to me. I did all as was shown here:https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks

Answer (score 2):

It works for me:

```
# telegram.py
def build():

    application = Application.builder().updater(None).persistence(persistence).token("TOKEN").build()
    ....
    return application

async def run(application, data):
    async with application:
        await application.start()
        await application.update_queue.put(
                Update.de_json(data=data, bot=application.bot)
            )
        await application.stop()


# views.py
def webhook(request, *args, **kw):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    application = telegram.build()
    asyncio.run(telegram.run(application, data))
    return HttpResponse('Ok')
```

For undestanding the persistence see this example: https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a4/examples.persistentconversationbot.html

I create a "build" function for fix "Thread Safe". (Application can be run only one loop)

The "run" function is only for help me with application start / update / stop. (You can be move for the async view).